# Very simple bind9 DNS server

Tags: dns, bind, bind9

I am using Debian server 10 and bind9 for my DNS server network, I want very simple working with DNS server, my topology is like below:

```
client <-> DNS <-> voip.example.com

client IP: 172.17.106.9
client DNS primary: 172.17.106.15
client DNS secondary: 8.8.8.8

DNS IP: 172.17.106.15

voip.example.com IP: 172.17.106.12
```

I want to check the DNS records when each request is received from the client, and if it does not match, go to the secondary DNS stored in the client's secondary DNS(8.8.8.8)

I get this error on client cmd:

```
C:\Users\Farhad>nslookup voip.example.com
Server:  ns1.example.com
Address:  172.17.106.15

*** ns1.example.com can't find voip.example.com: Server failed
```

my bind9 configuration is here:

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";            # zone file path
};

zone "17.172.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.172.17";                 # 172.17.0.0/16 subnet
};
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted" {
        172.17.106.15;  # ns1
        172.17.106.9;   # client
        172.17.106.12;  # VoIP
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
        allow-recursion { trusted; };  # allows recursive queries from "trusted" clients
        listen-on { 172.17.106.15; };   # ns1 private IP address - listen on private network only
        allow-transfer { none; };      # disable zone transfers by default

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

};
```

/etc/bind/db.example.com

```
$TTL    604800
@                               IN      SOA     ns1.example.com.    f.example.com. (
                                3               ; Serial
                                604800          ; Refresh
                                86400           ; Retry
                                2419200         ; Expire
                                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; name servers - NS records
                                IN      NS      ns1.example.com.

; name servers - A records
ns1.example.com.            IN      A       172.17.106.15

; 172.16.0.0/16 - A records
voip.example.com.           IN      A       172.17.106.12
```

/etc/bind/db.172.17

```
$TTL    604800
@               IN      SOA     ns1.example.com.    f.example.com. (
                3               ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; name servers
            IN      NS      ns1.example.com.

; PTR Records
15.106      IN      PTR     ns1.example.com.        ; 172.17.106.15
12.106      IN      PTR     voip.example.com.       ; 172.17.106.12
```

Comment: You have no `A` record for the host `farhad.example.com`. That explains `can't find` message, but the server should not fail on negative results, so there is some misconfiguration. Did you try an existing host like `www.google.com` to check if forwarding works? Did you look at bind log files?

Comment: sry, I changed my nslookup command

Comment: So it cannot resolve hosts in `example.com`.  Check named logs on ns1 and run command `named-checkzone example.com <path-to-zone-file>`

Comment: thank you @YuriGinsburg this resolve my IP correctly

Answer (score 0):

now it works fine with changed `db.example.com` and delete `ns2` record and resolve exactly IP address of `voip.example.com`

but my primary issue still exist:
I want to check the DNS records when each request is received from the client, and if it does not match, go to the secondary DNS stored in the client's secondary `DNS(8.8.8.8)`

for example some client request to reach `test.com` , and client have primary dns `172.17.106.15` and secondary dns `8.8.8.8`

query reviced from client to my dns server `172.17.106.15`, but did not go to `8.8.8.8`